# Clever/fast way of array multiplication and summation

Tags: arrays, fortran, integration, multiplication, do-loops

I have to solve a double integral

[image]

in my program, that can be translated into the `i-,j-` loops in the following minimum working example:

```
program test

  implicit none

  integer :: i, j, n
  double precision, allocatable :: y(:), res(:), C(:,:,:)

  n=200

  allocate(y(n), res(n), C(n,n,n))

  call random_number(y)
  call random_number(C)

  res = 0.d0
  do i=1, n
    do j=1, n
      res(:) = res(:) + y(i) * y(j) * C(:, j, i)
    end do
  end do

  deallocate(y, res, C)

end program test
```

I have to solve this integral multiple times per execution and profiling tells me that it's the bottle neck of my calculation consuming more than 95 % of the execution time.

I was wondering whether there's any possibility to solve this in a more clever, i.e., fast way and maybe get rid of one or both of the loops.

My question is not to optimize the code with compiler flags or parallelization, but whether the double loop is the best practice to tackle the given problem. Usually loops are slow and I try to avoid them. I was thinking that it might be possible to avoid the loops by reshaping or spreading the arrays. But I just don't see it.

Comment: Beyond that, how are you compiling (optimization flags, etc)?  And have you looked at access ordering?

Comment: His loop ordering is correct.

Comment: Please ignore everything outside the loop. That's only to provide a minimum working example that can easily be adjusted for the array size.
Why would ``res(:)`` make any difference?

Comment: @Jack Them loop ordering is incorrect - the innermost is that implied by C( j, i, : ) which is down the last index. This is the first thing I would try to fix

Comment: Ultimately this calculation takes a certain number of operations.  Once you have that efficiently implemented, you can reduce the clock time by multi-threading, e.g., with OpenMP.

Comment: On a train about to get off but getting the loops the right way round made about a factor of 2 increase in performance for me, and getting better as n increases. Will try to post answer later - but please try to beat me to it! Use of Dgemv in BLAS is another thing worth looking at.

Comment: The loop ordering is correct as it is. It's Fortran. The fastest index is the first one, in this case ``j``. I'm actually not looking for compiler flags or parallelization. My question is more theoretical whether this is the best practice to do this calculation. Usually I try to avoid loops. But I don't see any way to do this here. I'll have a look at Dgemv.

Comment: So if the fastest index is the first one, doing `C(j,i,:)` means you're accessing all of the elements for the slowest index for fixed `j` and `i` in the deepest part of your loop, in other words `C(:,j,i)` might be much better.

Comment: I see. You're right! Thanks!
Changed it.

Comment: *Usually loops are slow*  What !!!!

Comment: Yes, @IanBush.  I was thinking only of the `i` and `j` components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write the double loop in Matrix notation,`y(i)*y(j)` becomes the diadic `YY^t`, with Y being a n x 1 matrix. With this you can re-write the loop to (pseudo-code)

```
do n=1,size(C,1)
  res(n) = sum( YY^t * C_n )
enddo
```

where `C_n = C(n,:,:)` and `*` is an element-wise multiplication. Apart from the element-wise calculation you already did, this leaves you two additional ways of calculating the results:

1. `res(n) = sum( (YY^t) * C_n )`
2. `res(n) = sum( Y * (Y^t C_n) )`

In both cases, it is beneficial to have contiguous data and re-order the array `C`:

```
  do i=1,n
    C2(:,:,i) = C(i,:,:)
  enddo !i
```

The number of floating point operations is the same with both approaches and slightly less than in the original approach. So let's measure the time for all of them...

Here are the implementations using LAPACK for the matrix operations (and using dot products where applicable):

**1. `sum( (YY^t) * C_n )`**

```
  call system_clock(iTime1)
  call dgemm('N','N',n,n,1,1.d0,y,n,y,1,0.d0,mat,n)

  nn=n*n
  do i=1,n
    res(i) = ddot( nn, mat, 1, C2(:,:,i), 1 ) 
  enddo !i
```

**2. `sum( Y * (Y^t C_n) )`**

```
  do i=1,n
    call dgemm('N','N',1,n,n,1.d0,y,1,C2(:,:,i),n,0.d0,vec,1)
    res(i) = ddot( n, y, 1, vec, 1 ) 
  enddo !i
```

The outcome is as follows:

```
 Orig:   0.111000001    
 sum((YY^t)C):   0.116999999    
 sum(Y(Y^tC)):   0.187000006
```

Your original implementation is the fastest! Why? Most probably due to the ideal usage of the cache on the CPU. Fortran compilers typically are very smart in optimizing loops, and in the element-wise calculation, you simply add and scale vectors, without any matrix operation. This can be utilized very efficiently.

So, is there room for improvement? Certainly :) The operation you are performing inside the loop is commonly known as axpy: `y = a*x + y`. This is a commonly used BLAS subroutine - usually highly optimized. 
Utilizing this leads to

```
  res = 0.d0
  do i=1, n
    do j=1, n
      call daxpy(n, y(i)*y(j), C(:,j,i), 1, res, 1)
    end do
  end do
```

and takes

```
 Orig (DAXPY):   0.101000004
```

Which is roughly 10% faster.

---

Here is the complete code, all measurements have been performed with OpenBLAS and with `n=500` (to better see the impact)

```
program test

  implicit none

  integer :: i, j, n, nn
  double precision, allocatable, target :: y(:), res(:), resC(:), C(:,:,:), C2(:,:,:), mat(:,:), vec(:)
  integer           :: count_rate, iTime1, iTime2

  double precision :: ddot
  n=500

  allocate(y(n), res(n), resC(n), C(n,n,n), C2(n,n,n), mat(n,n), vec(n))

  call random_number(y)
  call random_number(C)

  ! Get the count rate
  call system_clock(count_rate=count_rate)

  ! Original Aproach
  call system_clock(iTime1)
  res = 0.d0
  do i=1, n
    do j=1, n
      res(:) = res(:) + y(i) * y(j) * C(:, j, i)
    end do
  end do
  call system_clock(iTime2)
  print *,'Orig: ',real(iTime2-iTime1)/real(count_rate)

  ! Original Aproach, DAXPY
  call system_clock(iTime1)
  resC = 0.d0
  do i=1, n
    do j=1, n
      call daxpy(n, y(i)*y(j), C(:,j,i), 1, resC, 1)
    end do
  end do
  call system_clock(iTime2)
  print *,'Orig (DAXPY): ',real(iTime2-iTime1)/real(count_rate)
!  print *,maxval( abs(resC-res) )

  ! Re-order
  do i=1,n
    C2(:,:,i) = C(i,:,:)
  enddo !i

  ! sum((YY^t)C)
  call system_clock(iTime1)
  call dgemm('N','N',n,n,1,1.d0,y,n,y,1,0.d0,mat,n)

  nn=n*n
  do i=1,n
    resC(i) = ddot( nn, mat, 1, C2(:,:,i), 1 ) 
  enddo !i
  call system_clock(iTime2)
  print *,'sum((YY^t)C): ',real(iTime2-iTime1)/real(count_rate)
!  print *,maxval( abs(resC-res) )

  ! sum(Y(Y^tC))
  call system_clock(iTime1)
  do i=1,n
    call dgemm('N','N',1,n,n,1.d0,y,1,C2(:,:,i),n,0.d0,vec,1)
    resC(i) = ddot( n, y, 1, vec, 1 ) 
  enddo !i
  call system_clock(iTime2)
  print *,'sum(Y(Y^tC)): ',real(iTime2-iTime1)/real(count_rate)
!  print *,maxval( abs(resC-res) )
end program test
```

Comment: Thanks! I can reproduce this on my computer with your code. ``daxpy`` is even about 9 times faster than the original approach.  However, when I implement it into my full code, it's about 20 % slower. I still have to figure out why this is.